# ClassNotFoundException for CypherCompiler class

Tags: maven, neo4j

Using Maven, I added neo4j:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.bureau13</groupId>
  <artifactId>rpglib</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <name>rpglib Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>                
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>rpglib</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

I wrote the following test:

```
public class Neo4JTest {
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( "rpglib" );

    ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( graphDb, null );

    Node createNode = graphDb.createNode();

    @Test
    public void testBootup() {
        try {
            Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();         
            createNode.setProperty("name", "Sword of Strength");
        } finally {

        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testFind() {        
        try {
            Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
            Node foundNode = graphDb.getNodeById( createNode.getId() );
        } finally {

        }
    }
}
```

I get the following exception in both tests:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v2_0/CypherCompiler
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.CypherCompiler.<init>(CypherCompiler.scala:61)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.createCompiler(ExecutionEngine.scala:150)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.<init>(ExecutionEngine.scala:48)
    at org.rpglib.persistence.Neo4JTest.<init>(Neo4JTest.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:195)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:244)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.CypherCompiler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
```

The offending class is org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v2_0/CypherCompiler.

However, while in Eclipse, I can see it in my Maven dependencies.

I can also see that I have three Cypher compiler dependencies:

- neo4j-cypher-compiler-1.9-2.0.3.jar
- neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.0-2.0.3.jar
- neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1-2.1.5.jar

Since it's looking for CypherCompiler in the v2_0 path, I excluded the compiler jars that don't have that path, and kept only the second one.. But when I did this, I got ClassNotFoundExceptions for classes in those jars.

There are 3 CypherCompiler classes present, but they all have different packages:

- org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v1_9/CypherCompiler
- org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v2_0/CypherCompiler
- org/neo4j/cypher/internal/compiler/v2_1/CypherCompiler

I'm at a loss. The jars have different package paths, so there should be no issue, right?

Comment: I can't fix your maven issue (not sure) but I know your test will fail.  When you run this:  `Node createNode = graphDb.createNode();` that will fail because you're not allowed to create a node outside of a transaction.  When your test class initializes, it will throw an exception.  That createNode() needs to be inside of a transaction.

Comment: Look in your local Maven repo for the `v2_0` jar and examine it using a zip viewer to see if those classes are indeed included. Also, examine the classpath argument(s) from your IDE and see that the jar you need is indeed being properly included.

Comment: Yep, class is in the jar. Also the jar is included on the Java build path as a maven dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from eclipse to Intellij IDEA fixed this for me. I still don't know what the original cause was.